# Why does combining multiple rows into one column duplicates data?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-concat

I know this question had been answered before but I couldn't find one with a similar problem.

I created an example table below:

```
TableA - aID | aName
          1  | House


TableB - bID | bmodel    | bname  | aID
          1  | studio    | classy |  1
          2  | studio    | small  |  1
          3  | apartment | classy |  1

TableC - cID | cmodel   | cname  | aID
          1  | bedroom  | big    | 1
          2  | bedroom  | small  | 1
          3  | bedroom  | big    | 1
```

I'm trying to achive

```
aID | aName |          bmodel bname                            |     cmodel cname
 1  | house | studio classy, studio small, apartment classy    | bed big, bed small, bed big
```

Here's what happens

```
aID | aName |          bmodel bname                                                                          |     cmodel cname
 1  | house | studio classy, studio small, apartment classy, studio classy, studio small, appartment classy  | bedroom big, bedroom small, bedroom small, bedroom big, bedroom small, bedroom small
```

It just repeats even more the more GROUP_CONCAT I add.

The code I used:

```
SELECT 
    TableA.aId, TableA.aname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(TableB.bmodel, ' ', TableB.bname) SEPARATOR ', ') as BModNam,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(TableC.cmodel, ' ', TableC.cname) SEPARATOR ', ') AS CModNam

FROM TableB
    JOIN cases
        ON TableB.aID = TableA.aId
    JOIN TableC
        ON TableC.aid = TableA.aID

WHERE
    TableA.aID=1
```

I know I could use distinct but would exclude rows that had duplicates (i.e. studio, classy, bedroom, big)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the calls to `GROUP_CONCAT` as subqueries in the select statement:

```
SELECT
    aID,
    aName,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b.bmodel, ' ', b.bname))
     FROM TableB b WHERE b.aID = t.aID GROUP BY b.aID) AS bmodel_bname,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.cmodel, ' ', c.cname))
     FROM TableC c WHERE c.aID = t.aID GROUP BY c.aID) AS cmodel_cname
FROM TableA t
WHERE aID = 1;
```

The problem with joining, and with your current output, is that you are multiplying together the sets of models and names from the two tables.  Using subqueries gets around this, because each subquery generates a focused CSV list for only that table.

**Output:**

```
aID aName   bmodel_bname                  cmodel_cname
1   House   studio classy,studio small,   bedroom big,bedroom small,
            apartment classy              bathroom big
```

## Demo

Comment: Thanks Tim! It worked! But Do you think using join messed up my output? I'd like to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: @SamFlynn The potential problem with joining is that you end up multiplying together the two sets of data from the two tables, which isn't what you want.  If you had more data the problem might get even worse.